How the implement a multi-objective optimization problem in Pymoo with x_ijm (three-dimensional array)
for my thesis I'm optimizing a multi-objective, multi-modal optimization model for commuting in Brussels. For this, I wrote 4 objective functions - minimizing travel time, travel cost, CO2 emissions and inconvinience - and 7 constraints - flow conservation, flow conservation at start and end node, car ownership, bike ownership, maximum walking distance and maximum travel time.
The input data consists of an Excel-file with connections and the corresponding transportation mode, travel time, emissions, distance, line name and number. There is also some user input.
I want to get an optimal solution, saying which transportation mode should be used for an edge (between 2 nodes) based on the constraints and objective functions.
I already wrote the code in Pymoo, but I'm stuck on the very last part. The code returns an optimal value of 0, and the array of x_ijm is equal to all zeros, which should not be the case.
The model I'm implementing can be found in the picture below:
Model in mathematical language(https://i.sstatic.net/0k0njREC.png)
This is the code I wrote to implement those objective functions and constraints:
Python code:
class TransportationProblem(ElementwiseProblem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(n_var=3,
                         n_obj=4,
                         n_constr=7,
                         xl=0,
                         xu=1)
        self.o_r_index = o_r_index
        self.e_r_index = e_r_index
        self.car_r = car_r
        self.bike_r = bike_r
        self.D_r = D_r
        self.T_r = T_r
        self.t_ijm = t_ijm
        self.c_ijm = c_ijm
        self.p_ijm = p_ijm
        self.w_ijm = w_ijm
        self.num_nodes = len(G.nodes())  # 887
        self.num_modes = 7
        self.x_ijm = np.zeros((self.num_nodes, self.num_nodes, self.num_modes))

    def _evaluate(self, x, out, *args, **kwargs):
        # Objective functions
        f1 = np.sum(np.sum(np.sum(t_ijm * self.x_ijm)))
        f2 = np.sum(np.sum(np.sum(c_ijm * self.x_ijm)))
        f3 = np.sum(np.sum(np.sum(p_ijm * self.x_ijm)))
        f4 = np.sum(np.sum(np.sum(w_ijm * self.x_ijm)))

        # Constraints
        g1 = np.sum(np.sum(self.x_ijm, axis=0) - np.sum(self.x_ijm, axis=1))
        g2 = np.sum(self.x_ijm[self.o_r_index, :, :]) - 1
        g3 = np.sum(self.x_ijm[:, self.e_r_index, :]) - 1
        g4 = np.sum(self.x_ijm[:, 0, 0], axis=0) - self.car_r
        g5 = np.sum(self.x_ijm[:, 0, 1], axis=0) - self.bike_r
        g6 = np.sum(np.sum(0.4 * self.x_ijm, axis=(0, 1)) - self.D_r)
        g7 = np.sum(np.sum(np.sum(self.t_ijm * self.x_ijm))) - self.T_r

        out["F"] = [f1, f2, f3, f4]  # Objective values
        out["G"] = [g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7]  # Constraint violations

So, when I run the program I get an optimal solution of 0, which should not be equal to 0 (I tested it with a small version of my dataset and can calculate manually what the optimal solution should be).The problem lies in the formulation/implementation of x_ijm, because this array is equal to all zeros. Normally, x_ijm should equal 1 if transportation mode m is used to travel from i to j, thus for the optimal mode for an edge. Everything else works in the code: the other arrays of objective values are filled in.
How should I program this in order to not get all zeros for x_ijm, but get for some combinations of i, j, and m a 1?
